# Print word document with duplex

Tags: vb.net, printing, duplex

My code:

```
Dim prtdoc As New PrintDocument
Dim oDoc As Word.Document

oDoc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument
oDoc.PageSetup.FirstPageTray = 260
oDoc.PrintOut()
```

How can I print it with duplex?

Comment: The PrintOut() method has an optional ManualDuplexPrint argument, sounds good.

Comment: thanks for reply. i have tried that option but it will give you the option to do it manual.. but my printer do have the automatix duplex option, in other word i can do it automaticaly???

Comment: No idea with "automatix" might mean.  If it is automatic then why do you need to help?

Comment: ok, if i set this property to true then i would be able to print as duplex manually and if set to false or leave blank it will not print as duplex, seems to be like i need to set the flag for duplex.. but dont know how oi can do that.... :(